# webapi issue in asp.net using visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am new to `WebAPI`. My question is, how to consume `WebAPI` from another ASP.Net Web API. I have done some codes and I don't know how to do GET and POST requests with parameter and without parameter.

This is my `apicontroller` code:

```
namespace CelusionWebapi.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        ClientCall client = new ClientCall();
        // GET: api/Test
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "Hello ", "Arjun" };
        }

        // GET: api/Test/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "Hello This Is Arjun ";
        }

        // POST: api/Test
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        public async Task<Employee> CheckMapping(Employee mapping)
        {
            string Baseurl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestBaseurl"].ToString();

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //Passing service base url  
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                //Define request data format  
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); 
                HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync(string.Format("Get?id={0}", mapping.EmployeeId));             
                if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                    var EmpResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var promapping = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Employee>>(EmpResponse.Result);
                    mapping = await Res.Content.ReadAsAsync<Employee>();                 
                }
                //returning the employee list to view  
                return mapping;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This is my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CelusionWebapi.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string EmployeeName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Address
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public string Department

        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

My `JSON` is as below

```
[{"employeeId":1,"employeeName":"Arjun walmiki","address":"Thane","department":"IT"},{"employeeId":2,"employeeName":"Rahul","address":"Thane","department":"HR"},{"employeeId":3,"employeeName":"Ajay","address":"Thane","department":"Sales"}]
```

Comment: Your not even calling your method `CheckMapping` not sure what you're expecting...

Comment: I think he is calling the `CheckMapping` API from outside world and trying to call an another API from that API.

Comment: Have you tried calling the second API using any tools like Postman or Fiddler, just to make sure that it i working fine as expected?

Comment: Yes i check my webapi using Postman

Comment: How can and where i use my CheckMapping method that is my issue if you know kindly mentioned how can i use it in my code?

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace CelusionWebapi.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        private const string Baseurl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestBaseurl"].ToString();
        private static readonly HttpClient client;
        public static TestController(){
            client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); 
        }

        // GET: api/Test
        public Enumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "Hello ", "Arjun" };
        }

        // GET: api/Test/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "Hello This Is Arjun ";
        }

        // POST: api/Test
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Employee employee)
        {
            empolyee = await CheckMapping(employee);
            ... do something with Employee
            return this.created(//location, employee);
        }

        private async Task<Employee> CheckMapping(Employee mapping)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage Res = await this.client.GetAsync(string.Format("Get?id={0}", mapping.EmployeeId));             
            if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                mapping = await Res.Content.ReadAsAsync<Employee>();                 
            }
            //returning the employee list to view  
            return mapping;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you ATerry  but i am geeting error on line no  client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl); error An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property Or many error

Comment: i am getting many error i will fix and let you if any issue or my code is working or not

Comment: Baseurl needs a web config value.

Comment: Thank you i got solution

Answer (score 0):

i have done some changes in my code and solution is as below :-

```
namespace CelusionWebapi.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {

        // GET: api/Test
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> Get()
        {

            List<Employee> employee = new List<Employee>();
            employee = await GetAllEmployees();
            return employee;
        }


        // POST: api/Test
        public void Post([FromBody]Models.Employee employee)
        {

        }
        [NonAction]
        public async Task<List<Employee>> GetAllEmployees()
        {

            string Baseurl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestBaseurl"].ToString();

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //Passing service base url  
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                //Define request data format  
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync(string.Format("GetAllEmployees"));
                List<Employee> emoloyeelist = new List<Employee>();
                if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                    var EmpResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                   emoloyeelist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(EmpResponse.Result);

                }
                //returning the employee list to view  
                return emoloyeelist;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you to all